Azure Container Apps Service to use Managed built-in policy definition
There is 1 policy definition on Managed Identity in Azure for Container Apps.

Managed Identity should be enabled for Container Apps

Just curious on how this built-in policy apply as i am new with policies. Can someone help on how to use or demonstrate a configuration how to assign the policy definition and use in Container Apps Service?
Thank you and looking for the experts here.

Locate the Built-in Policy Definition, under definition section search bar look for "Managed Identity should be enabled for Container Apps" built-in policy. or even from CLI you can get it az policy definition list --query "[?contains(displayName, 'Managed Identity should be enabled for Container Apps')]" -o table' Now, assign the policy to your resource group using the policy definition ID , Verify Policy Assignment- az policy assignment list --scope "/subscriptions/$(az account show --query 'id' -o tsv)/resourceGroups/$RESOURCE_GROUP" -o table`.

After assigning the policy, Azure will evaluate the compliance of existing Container Apps within the arkorg resource group. az policy state summarize --query "[?contains(policyAssignmentName, '$POLICY_NAME')]" -o table

Checkout MS docs- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/policy/definition?view=azure-cli-latest#az-policy-definition-list and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.policyinsights/get-azpolicystatesummary?view=azps-13.0.0&viewFallbackFrom=azps-12.4.0

Thank you @Arko, i will try this as well.

To apply the built-in Azure Policy "Managed Identity should be enabled for Container Apps", follow these steps to ensure that all Container Apps in your specified scope have Managed Identity enabled
In search type Policy, under that look for definitions on the left side column, under Definitions, search for "Managed Identity should be enabled for Container Apps"

You can also use CLI
az policy definition list --query "[?contains(displayName, 'Managed Identity should be enabled for Container Apps')]" -o table


Assign the policy to your target scope for example your resource group under which you will deploy your ACA
az policy assignment create \ --name $POLICY_NAME \ --scope "/subscriptions/$SUBSCRIPTION_ID/resourceGroups/$RESOURCE_GROUP" \ --policy $POLICY_ID


Done. You can validate the same by deploying a test container App
Let's say this one is non-compliant, another is compliant. The policy should tell you now if it's non-compliant
az containerapp create \
  --name test-noncompliant-app \
  --resource-group <your-resource-group-name> \
  --environment <your-container-app-environment-name> \
  --image mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/containerapps-helloworld:latest


Now check. trigger a fresh scan
az policy state trigger-scan --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP


Let it run. Once you get the prompt back now check-
az policy state list \
  --filter "policyAssignmentName eq '$POLICY_NAME'" \
  --query "[?complianceState=='NonCompliant'].{Resource: resourceId, Compliance: complianceState}" \
  -o table


You can check the same from portal as well

You can even prevent non-compliant resources from being created, enable enforcement mode. Checkout - Tutorial: Create and manage policies to enforce compliance and  MS Doc

This is very informative to me and hope to others also. I will try this config and will update you on the result. Thank you so much!

Can you please raise one more issue related to your requirement in details so that the community will try to answer?

Did you follow each and every step I mentioned? It should come, as I have shown in the output. Check if you are missing out any step? Update your question with what all you have tried so far?

Yes, i successfully got the compliance result. Another question here is Remediation on non-compliance is applicable in this policy or NOT?

Did you get a chance to read the article I shared for remediation on non complaint containers? First is enforcing the compliance. checkout that doc. Another way is in the policy page itself where you are seeing that 50% on top of that you can see there is an option. you can create remediation task. kindly checkout- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/how-to/remediate-resources?tabs=azure-portal

I am trying now to Enforcing the Compliance. Create Remediation Task is greyed out cannot be clicked that is why need to confirm if remediation is applicable.

To create a remediation task kindly follow the steps mentioned here- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/how-to/remediate-resources?tabs=azure-portal#create-a-remediation-task

See comment and screenshot above, remediation task is unable to run, definition is not showing at all.
